# react-select : Conditional styling of select objects

Tags: react-select

I am seeking a very specific behavior from react-select. I want to be able to apply a custom style (backgroundColor: "blue") to a specific subset of the dropdown options of the  component. However, it appears that there is no easy way to do this because I can't access the conditional I need in the styles prop.

Example:
So, suppose there are 6 options. I want three of those options to have a specific style (different color) based based on a condition being true and the others have the normal style.

Here is a picture depicting what I would like to achieve:

[Dropdown, 3 blue 3 normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbhGK.png)

Thanks for all of your help.

```
let optionsIn = [{ value:0, label:"Label1", shouldBeBlue:true },
           { value:1, label:"Label2", shouldBeBlue:true },
           { value:2, label:"Label3", shouldBeBlue:true }, 
           { value:3, label:"Label4", shouldBeBlue:false },  
           { value:4, label:"Label5", shouldBeBlue:false },
           { value:5, label:"Label6", shouldBeBlue:false },
          ]

<Select
options={optionsIn}
/>
```

So in this case, Label1, Label2, and Label3 should all have a background-color of blue inside react-select, but Label4, Label5, and Label6 should just be rendered normally.

Comment: Hi doobie. I suggest you post some of your React code.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. You can access the options prop with { data } parameter:

```
      let optionsIn = [{ value:0, label:"Label1", shouldBeBlue:true },
       { value:1, label:"Label2", shouldBeBlue:true },
       { value:2, label:"Label3", shouldBeBlue:true }, 
       { value:3, label:"Label4", shouldBeBlue:false },  
       { value:4, label:"Label5", shouldBeBlue:false },
       { value:5, label:"Label6", shouldBeBlue:false },
      ]

                  <Select
                    options={optionsIn}
                    styles={{
                      option: (styles, { data }) => {
                        return {
                          ...styles,
                          backgroundColor: data.shouldBeBlue
                            ? "blue"
                            : undefined
                        };
                      }
                    }}
                  />
```